# Non-invocable member'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management. IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder.Projects' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, ssis, server, integration

i try to get values in string

```
integrationServices = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString));

string catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs("SSISDB");   

string catalogFolder = catalog.Folders(folderName);   

string package = catalogFolder.Projects(projectName).Packages(packageName);    

executionId = package.Execute(use32BitRuntime, null);
```

but i getting this error even i used conversions methods 
Thanks,

Comment: Project is a collection...try using [] brackets to access it...or Google https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.projectcollection.aspx

Comment: @Slimon Wilson Thank you ..